# Excel 2003/2007 row height feature output error

Tags: windows, vba, excel

In Excel 2003, tried this on Excel 2007 also, on a random chosen cell the user enters a number which represents pixels. I want to re-size the row which contains the cell, according to this number of pixels, but since Excel 2003 and 2007 are using points for row height, how do I convert pixels to points ?

I have used this formula (nr of pixels in cell ) * 0.75 and implemented as such in vba 6

Rows(RI).RowHeight = Cells(RI, ColumnIndex).Value * 0.75

Works best in most cases, but, I know it sounds really crazy, sometimes when this value is 5 or 15 or 25 or 35 or 45, maybe other numbers, the row height ends up re-sized to 6, 16, 26, 36, 46 piexels, simulating the fact that Excel does not have a correspondent in points for this values.

The same thing happens when I go to a row, right click on it, row height... feature, give an input of 4,5,  4.5 points = 5 px * 0.75, and sometimes the row is re-sized to 6 px.

Am I really crazy or did you encountered this phenomenon before ?

thank you for all your time,

kind regards,

radu

Answer (score 1):

You are not crazy, many of the numbers in Excel have no logic that I have discovered.  However the following methods and property may help:

```
PointsToScreenPixelsX
PointsToScreenPixelsY
PixelsPerInch
InchesToPoints
CentimetersToPoints
```

I should add that the conversion from pixels to points is font and font size specific.

Comment: thank you very much Tony, so you are saying something like Rows(RI).RowHeight = Something.PointsToScreenPixelsX(Cells(RI, ColumnIndex).Value * 0.75)  ???

Comment: and could you please explain this : 
I should add that the conversion from pixels to points is font and font size specific.

Comment: Pixels are dots on the screen which do not change size for a given screen.  Higher resolution screens have smaller and more pixels.  Points identify the size of a font with Arial 10 being smaller than Arial 12.  Some fonts are bigger than others so XXXX 10 is not necessarily the same size as YYYY 10.  Try Googling for "Printer Points" for a fuller explanation.

Comment: I think I have mislead you.  I have not needed to set cell widths and heights for many years.  I remembered the names of methods which are very difficult to discover unless you know their names so I passed them on to you.  I do not remember how I used them.  Having played with them for the last hour, I am not sure I did use them. The PointsToScreenPixels methods only operate on Windows.  I cannot see that the other routines offer anything useful either.  Perhaps if you can explain what you are trying to achieve, I will remember something useful.